# Display a Whole Number or Decimal field as a Percent in a PowerApps Model Driven Form

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, power-platform, powerapps-modeldriven

I have a field in one of my entity’s that is a whole number datatype, is there a way to display it as a percent in a Model Driven Form? That is if the value for example is 90, I want to display it as 90%. Do I need to use a Flow\Power Automate to convert it to a text and append a % to the end?
Also, I have decimal field in the same entity that I need to also display as a % and not something like this .90.

I have not found a way to format a whole number or decimal number as a % on a Model Driven form or view. I think in a Canvas Application this is fairly easy to do.

Comment: After doing some more research, you cannot add a % sign on a Model Driven Form, but this is a PCF control that can display a whole number or decimal as a %
https://pcf.gallery/progress-control/

Comment: yes, thats right. PCF is the way to go.